# Calendar view doesn't work in html5 sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html, calendar

I am creating an application in django and I have the next problem. I have some search forms in the application, and in some of them there are fields of type 'DateField'. In addition, I have implemented a jQuery function to display a calendar view when the user clicks on those date fields. The code is the next:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $( ".vDateField" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work always. In some pages, the calendar view is displayed correctly, but in a few others not. I have put correctly the class 'vDateField' to the DateField attributes in all the forms in django like this:

```
 self.fields['date'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'vDateField'}
```

So, why doesn't it sometimes work?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the class successfully applied by Django? Or asked differently: Is this a Django-issue or a jQuery-issue?

Comment: Try using chrome debugger or say similar tool to see what happens with the JS code and check whether the class name is same and it reflects there.

Comment: When the calendar view is not displayed, I get the next error in the JavaScript Console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap you code in `$(document).ready`
e.g.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function() {
       $( ".vDateField" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I try it but I continue having the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"